# discord.js unban command has.permission

Tags: node.js, discord.js, nodemon

```
        if (message.content.startsWith('L!unban')) {
            if (message.author.hasPermission(["BAN_MEMBERS"])) return message.channel.send("You do not have the required permissions to use the unban command.")
    
            if (args[0]) return message.channel.send("Provide me a valid USER ID.");
            //This if() checks if we typed anything after "!unban"
    
            let bannedMember;
            //This try...catch solves the problem with the await
            try {
                bannedMember = await bot.users.cache.fetch(args[0])
            } catch (e) {
                if (!bannedMember) return message.channel.send("That's not a valid USER ID.")
            }
    
            //Check if the user is not banned
            try {
                await message.guild.fetchBan(args[0])
            } catch (e) {
                message.channel.send('This user is not banned.');
                return;
            }
    
            let reason = args.slice(1).join(" ")
            if (reason) reason = "No reason provided."
    
            if (message.guild.me.hasPermission(["BAN_MEMBERS"])) return message.channel.send("I am missing permissions to unban.")
            message.delete()
            try {
                message.guild.members.unban(bannedMember, { reason: reason })
                message.channel.send(`${bannedMember.tag} has been unbanned.`)
            } catch (e) {
                console.log(e.message)
            }
        }
    });
```

thats my code
now my question is that im trying to get this cmd working but everytime i use the cmd L!unban the `message.author.hasPermission` keeps saying that >TypeError: message.author.hasPermission is not a function is there a way to fix this?

Comment: `message.author` gives you a `User` object which doesn't have permissions. You want the `GuildMember` object instead. To access this, just use `message.member`

Comment: TypeError: message.member.hasPermission is not a function thats the error when i use ```client.on('messageCreate', async message => {
  if (message.content.startsWith('L!unban')) {
   if (message.member.hasPermission(["BAN_MEMBERS"])) return message.channel.send("You do not have the required permissions to use the unban command.")```

Answer (score 0):

If you use v14 it would be something like:

```
    if (message.content.startsWith('L!unban')) {
        if (message.member.permissions.has("BAN_MEMBERS")) return message.channel.send("You do not have the required permissions to use the unban command.")

        if (args[0]) return message.channel.send("Provide me a valid USER ID.");
        //This if() checks if we typed anything after "!unban"

        let bannedMember;
        //This try...catch solves the problem with the await
        try {
            bannedMember = await bot.users.cache.fetch(args[0])
        } catch (e) {
            if (!bannedMember) return message.channel.send("That's not a valid USER ID.")
        }

        //Check if the user is not banned
        try {
            await message.guild.fetchBan(args[0])
        } catch (e) {
            message.channel.send('This user is not banned.');
            return;
        }

        let reason = args.slice(1).join(" ")
        if (reason) reason = "No reason provided."

        if (message.guild.me.hasPermission(["BAN_MEMBERS"])) return message.channel.send("I am missing permissions to unban.")
        message.delete()
        try {
            message.guild.members.unban(bannedMember, { reason: reason })
            message.channel.send(`${bannedMember.tag} has been unbanned.`)
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e.message)
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: g'day grill 
just tried the `message.guild.member.permission.has` 
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'has') thanks for trying!!!

Comment: Im sorry, but are you using version v 14 or 13?

Comment: version 14.6.0 :)

Comment: It's not `permission`, it is `permissions` with an 's' at the end